# firebase transaction not maintaining priority?

Tags: firebase

I have been developing an app for a couple of months, and just today I noticed that whenever an item is changed inside a transaction, the item no longer has a priority assigned.

I'm quite sure it's been working up until recently (if not in fact yesterday but I'd hate to proclaim I'm 100% sure on that) so I'm wondering if this is a new bug.

In some of my architecture, I store the same information that needs to go into the priority, so it's a simple matter of adding the ".priority" member back in before returning the item at the end of the transaction code, but if I didn't store it anywhere else this would cause me real grief. It also, of course, seems counterproductive ;)

Anyone else noticed this, or does it sound like a side-effect of something else I could be doing?

I'm still using angularFire 0.3 since that's what was out/stable when I built this, but my transaction code relevant to this issue is all firebase API only - I'm letting the changes trickle from the server up to any angularFire objects.

Thanks for any help,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there are currently a couple issues around transactions and priority in the JS client and they're a little confusing (sometimes it won't keep the current priority when it should, and sometimes it /will/ keep the current priority, even if you included a different .priority child).  As a workaround, if you just want to preserve the current priority, including .priority with the current priority should work.

That said, I don't think anything has changed recently, so if you're seeing something new, that is surprising.  In any case, these issues should be addressed in the next few weeks.  If you need specific help, feel free to ping support@firebase.com with details about how you're using transactions and we can probably provide some advice.

I'll update this post once the issues are resolved.  Sorry!

Comment: Thanks a bunch Michael! I will have to do some work to avoid changing priorities it seems, as we were hoping to 'go live' with this app very soon. In my case, I am pretty sure I'll be able to do it, because there is only one transaction that is on a complex structure with a priority.

Comment: FWIW it's worth noting that I don't always succeed, even when setting the priority right before the return statement. However, I seem to see this particular transaction get interrupted and wind up running more than once, which could be exacerbating things. I will also see if there's any way to simplify the transaction into a smaller one operating on only a sub-member of this structure. Cheers!

Comment: Cool, sounds good.  If you get stuck, you can ping me at michael@firebase.com.  There should definitely be a way to make it work and let you guys go live. :-)